# How can I solve a SonarQube complainer in for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, sonarqube

I wrote a method copies bytes from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

```
// copies bytes from given input stream to specified output stream
// returns the number of bytes copied.
private static long copy(final InputStream input,
                         final OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    long count = 0L;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) != -1; count += length) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return count;
}
```

And SonarQube complains.

> This loop's stop condition tests "length, input, buffer" but the incrementer updates "count".
>
> It is almost always an error when a for loop's stop condition and incrementer don't act on the same variable. Even when it is not, it could confuse future maintainers of the code, and should be avoided.

Is there any better code for the same purpose?

**Update**

As answers recommended, I did like this and the problem's gone.

```
// copies bytes from given input stream to specified output stream
// returns the number of bytes copied.
private static long copy(final InputStream input,
                         final OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    long count = 0L;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        count += length;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea about SonarQube, but I would prefer to use `while` loop in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `count += length` in the for loop body instead. It isn't an incrementer and therefor doesn't belong there, it just keeps count of the copy size.

Answer (score 6):

You are abusing the `for` loop, that's why SonarQube raises a warning. In the following loop, you are incrementing `count` in the update clause but the stop condition does not depend on `count`

```
for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) != -1; count += length) {
                 ^---------------------------------^  ^-------------^
                      does not depend on count        increments count
```

Instead, you should use a `while` loop and increment the count inside the loop body:

```
private static long copy(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    long count = 0;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        count += length;
    }
    return count;
}
```